Error deserializing event after upgrading AWS Lambda project from .NET 6 to .NET 8
I am in the process of trying to upgrade an old AWS Lambda ASP.NET Core WebApi project but it fails when running it on AWS.
The project used to work with a LocalEntryPoint.cs file which contained the following lines:
var lambdaEntry = new LambdaEntryPoint();
var functionHandler = lambdaEntry.FunctionHandlerAsync;
LambdaBootstrapBuilder.Create<APIGatewayProxyRequest>(functionHandler, new DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer(x =>
    {
        x.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
        x.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
    }))
.Build()
.RunAsync().Wait();

This method does not seem to work anymore and I replaced it with a Program.cs file containing builder.Services.AddAWSLambdaHosting(LambdaEventSource.ApplicationLoadBalancer);
Yet when running the project on AWS I get this error with every event:

Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.JsonSerializerException: Error converting the Lambda event JSON payload to type Amazon.Lambda.ApplicationLoadBalancerEvents.ApplicationLoadBalancerRequest: Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported. Type 'Amazon.Lambda.ApplicationLoadBalancerEvents.ApplicationLoadBalancerRequest'.

From what I understand these events are locked behind the AWS Nuget libraries so I can't edit them.

And just as I posted this I found out what was wrong. Gonna leave the answer here in case someone has issues:
Our build pipeline was still using .net 6. After upgrading that one to .net 8 it now works
